# Help Required With Graph Plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph

I am about to present my work that I have created in MATLAB, but I am having trouble manipulating my data into a presentable form using the plot function.

My code looks like this:

```
[inputname, pathname] = uigetfile('*.wav', 'Select WAV-file');

thumb1 = inputname;               %# Get filename information
fprintf('\n%s is being turned into a 30s thumbnail...\n', thumb1);
fprintf('Please wait..!\n\n');
%# load the signal
[y, fs, nb] = wavread(thumb1);
y = mean(y,2);                               %# stereo, take avrg of 2 channels

%# Calculate frame energy
fWidth = round(fs*10e-3);                    %# 10ms
numFrames = floor(length(y)/fWidth);
energy = zeros(1,numFrames);
for f=1:numFrames
  energy(f) = sum( y((f-1)*fWidth+1:f*fWidth).^2 );
end
```

Basically I want to plot the energy of the track over time (in seconds).

```
plot(energy)
```

nearly does what I require, but I have an unusual amount of blank space at the end of the track which is not present in the .wav file[image]. This blank space is the main issue that I'm having. Ideally I would like the x axis to be displayed in seconds! Any help would be much appreciated.

**edit1:**

Using the first suggested method:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also

```
axis tight
```

which sets "tight" limits for the axis. See doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, Matlab uses some heuristic rules to choose the limits of graph scales.  You can override them with the `xlim` and `ylim` functions (e.g. `xlim([0 length(energy)])`).

If you want to plot against actual time, you can do something like:

```
t = (0:length(energy)-1) / fs;  % Timebase in seconds
plot(t, energy);
```

Comment: That still isn't quite what i'm looking for i'm afraid. I've updated the original post with what it looks like using your suggestion.

Comment: @Mark: Did `xlim` not do what you want?

Comment: Sorry I totally glazed over that part. I apologise. @Edric's suggestion worked perfectly though, but thank you for the help.